# How do we link rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to link single column data in such a way that it removes consecutive duplicate data and link it with the next row. Below is an example of data.

```
|  id  |  order_id |  issue_id  
------------------------------- 
|  1   |  7735436  |  795   
|  2   |  7735436  |  795   
|  3   |  7735436  |  94   
|  4   |  7735436  |  94   
|  5   |  7735436  |  795   
|  6   |  7735436  |  795   
|  7   |  7735436  |  42   
|  8   |  7735436  |  42   
|  9   |  7735436  |  795   
|  10  |  7735436  |  758   
|  11  |  7735436  |  758   
|  14  |  935437   |  23   
|  15  |  935437   |  23   
|  16  |  935437   |  91   
|  17  |  935437   |  92   
|  18  |  935437   |  92   
|  19  |  935437   |  105   
|  20  |  935437   |  105   
|  21  |  935437   |  105   
|  22  |  935437   |  82   
|  23  |  935437   |  82   
|  24  |  935437   |  10
```

The expected output is

```
|  order_id | link_1 | link_2   
----------------------------
|  7735436  | 795    | 94   
|  7735436  | 94     | 795   
|  7735436  | 795    | 42  
|  7735436  | 42     | 795  
|  7735436  | 795    | 758   
|  935437   | 23     | 91   
|  935437   | 91     | 92  
|  935437   | 92     | 105 
|  935437   | 105    | 82   
|  935437   | 82     | 10
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Why is there no 758,23 in your expected output? AND why are ids 12,13 missing from your data?

Comment: @P.Salmon Because order_id is getting changed and I need a link for each order_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Analytic (Window) function problem, needing the usage of [`Lead()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead). However, these goodies became available in [MySQL 8.0.2+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html) only; so in your case (MySQL 5.7), one solution is to utilize [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT t1.order_id, 
           t1.issue_id AS link_1, 
           (SELECT t2.issue_id 
            FROM your_table_name AS t2 
            WHERE t2.id > t1.id 
                  AND t2.order_id = t1.order_id 
                  AND t2.issue_id <> t1.issue_id 
            ORDER BY t2.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS link_2 
FROM your_table_name AS t1
```

**Result : [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/benotuFqQ1DryJAnnwo5Y3/0)**

```
| order_id | link_1 | link_2 |
| -------- | ------ | ------ |
| 7735436  | 795    | 94     |
| 7735436  | 94     | 795    |
| 7735436  | 795    | 42     |
| 7735436  | 42     | 795    |
| 7735436  | 795    | 758    |
| 7735436  | 758    |        |
| 935437   | 23     | 91     |
| 935437   | 91     | 92     |
| 935437   | 92     | 105    |
| 935437   | 105    | 82     |
| 935437   | 82     | 10     |
| 935437   | 10     |        |
```

Now, in the above approach, you get two additional rows corresponding to the case when there is no `link_2` (no subsequent `issue_id` for the `order_id`). You can ignore them in your application code; or make your query handle it further in the `WHERE` clause; or use a subquery ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html)). I would prefer to handle it in Application code, instead of burdening the query further.

---

However, if you want to handle everything within the SQL query itself, there you go:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT t1.order_id, 
           t1.issue_id AS link_1, 
           (SELECT t2.issue_id 
            FROM your_table_name AS t2 
            WHERE t2.id > t1.id 
                  AND t2.order_id = t1.order_id 
                  AND t2.issue_id <> t1.issue_id 
            ORDER BY t2.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS link_2 
FROM your_table_name AS t1 
WHERE 
(SELECT t2.issue_id 
            FROM your_table_name AS t2 
            WHERE t2.id > t1.id 
                  AND t2.order_id = t1.order_id 
                  AND t2.issue_id <> t1.issue_id 
            ORDER BY t2.id ASC LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
```

**Result#2 : [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/benotuFqQ1DryJAnnwo5Y3/1)**

```
| order_id | link_1 | link_2 |
| -------- | ------ | ------ |
| 7735436  | 795    | 94     |
| 7735436  | 94     | 795    |
| 7735436  | 795    | 42     |
| 7735436  | 42     | 795    |
| 7735436  | 795    | 758    |
| 935437   | 23     | 91     |
| 935437   | 91     | 92     |
| 935437   | 92     | 105    |
| 935437   | 105    | 82     |
| 935437   | 82     | 10     |
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya no need to use inner query just use `having` clause.

Comment: @JaydeepMor Although MySQL allows this non-ANSI-standard SQL behaviour; but it also recommends against it. Please read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html  *"The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior ... Do not use HAVING for items that should be in the WHERE clause"* Sorry I had to reject your Edit, as I would prefer the answer to be closer to SQL standard

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya This looks great to me. Thanks a lot for your time! :)